# Sufficient coordinate-free condition for points being co-spheric

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, simplicial-stuff, euclidean-geometry, counterexamples

**Question:**
is there a theorem that guarantees that
$\mathcal{P}\subset\mathbb{E}^n$ is finite set of points in a Euclidean space and all radii of the $(n-1)$-[spheres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Dimensionality) that are defined by the $n$-[simplices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) with $n$ corners in $\mathcal{P}$ are equal $\implies$
the centers of the circumspheres are identical.

Calculating the radius of a simplexes circumsphere is possible by means of sidelengths , cf e.g. https://westy31.home.xs4all.nl/Circumsphere/ncircumsphere.htm.

I want to utilize the above criterion for being co-spheric in a graph-theoretic algorithm and want to be sure that no "exotic" exception is lurking somewhere.

**Edit:**

the not so "exotic" counter example of @fedja

[image]

Comment: A tiny point of vocabulary : corners -> vertices

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker I use *corners* to hint the geometric interpretation whereas I tend to reserve *vertex* for graph theoretic interpretations. In geometry vertices need not be corners; e.g. the *vertex* of a parabola as depicted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola)

Comment: Take four noncoplanar  points of your group. They determine a sphere who's radius and center can be determined  geometrically. Think of one of these points asthe North Pole of the sphere and consider the stereographic projection onto the tangent plane to the South pole.  You are now left to decide if the projection of the remaining  remaining points are coplanar. That is an easier proposition.

Comment: Three vertices of an equilateral triangle on the plane together with its center give a sure counterexample but I wouldn't call this one "exotic" :-). It looks like the statement may, indeed, hold if the points are sufficiently many though...

Comment: @fedja in your example there are four simplices of which the three that contain the centerpoint have equal radius of circum circle, but the equilateral triangle's radius is different or did I miss the point? Maybe I have to edit my question.

Comment: @ManfredWeis How is it different? The arc corresponding to the inscribed angle of 120 degrees on the triangle side has the same radius as that for 60 degrees because 120+60=180. Am I misinterpreting your definition of "circumscribed" :-)

Comment: @fedja you are of course right; sorry for my mental blockage.